# Multiple Outlook Add-ink Panes Displaying at the Same Time

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have developed an Outlook web Add-in but currently when the task pane is open and we open another outlook add-in, our one closes and is replaced with the last selected one. Is there a way to have the task panes stack next to one another so that you can have more than one task pane open at the same time. Appreciate that screen real-estate is an issue but at least 2 would be nice. I thought that I had seen this working somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to have two add-ins open side-by-side. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

You can make your add-in [pinnable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane), this way your add-in will not be closed when another add-in is opened.